# $X$ is $T_0$ iff $\forall x,y \in X$ $x\ne y$ it holds that $\overline{\{x\}}\ne \overline{\{y\}}$.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Show that $X$ is $T_0$ iff $\forall x,y \in X$ $x\ne y$ it holds that $\overline{\{x\}}\ne \overline{\{y\}}$.

I was having trouble making a decisive, clear argument in what seems to be an easy question.
At first I attempted to show that if $X$ is $T_0$, then for $x,y\in X$ such that $x\ne y$, there exist $U_x, U_y \in T$ which respectively includes $x$ and not $y$ and vice-versa. Thus letting $F_x=X\setminus U_y, F_y=X\setminus U_x$, it follows that $\overline{\{x\}}\subset \overline{\{x\}}\cap F_x$ and that $\overline{\{y\}}\subset \overline{\{y\}}\cap F_y$, but can I directly derrive that $\overline{\{x\}}\ne \overline{\{y\}}$?

The opposite direction is confusing to me: for distinct $x,y \in X$, letting $F_x= \overline{\{x\}},F_y= \overline{\{y\}}$, if I can assume $y\notin F_x$ and $x\notin F_y$ then it is direct, but what if $x\in F_y$? I can't find an elegant way to adress this case.

What am I missing?
I accept that this question could be well-known and is a possible duplicate but I would appreciate it if you could address my strategy in-question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A space is $T_{0}$ if and only if the closures of singletons are distinct](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56101/a-space-is-t-0-if-and-only-if-the-closures-of-singletons-are-distinct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes very close to [$T_0$-identification of a topological space, proof using singleton closures](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3394780).

1. Let $X$ be $T_0$. If $x \ne y$, then there exists an open $U \subset X$ containing exactly one of $x,y$. So w.lo.g. we may assume $x \in U, y \notin U$. Then $y \in X \setminus U$ and thus $\overline{\{y\}}\subset  X \setminus U$. But then $\overline{\{x\}} = \overline{\{y\}}$ is impossible: Otherwise $x \in \overline{\{x\}} \subset X \setminus U$, i.e. $x \notin U$ which is a contradiction.
2. Let $X$ be not $T_0$. Then there exist distinct $x, y\in X$  such that each open $U \subset X$ either contains both $x,y$ or none of $x,y$. Hence the same is true for $X\setminus U$. Therefore

> Each closed $C \subset X$ either contains both $x,y$ or none of $x,y$.

We conclude that $\overline{\{x\}} = \overline{\{y\}}$.